# Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Tags: php

I have both GD and Freetype installed but I can't make it work.
The server run CentOS 5 with cpanel.

I read on php.net that I need to compile PHP with more options with

```
--with-gd
--enable-gd-native-ttf
--with-png
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib/zlib-1.2.1
--with-ttf
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/jpeg-6b/
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib/freetype-2.1.9/
--with-xpm-dir=/usr/X11R6/
```

However, I can't figure out where I should type this.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
    --with-freetype
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib/freetype-2.1.9/
```

Comment: where i should put this? if i write it in command line it says that the command is not found

Comment: please check if php-gd installed or not: rpm -qa|grep php, if not try install using yum php-gd. if you cannot install using yum you need to download the php source code and compile it using ./configure --with-freetype --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib/freetype-2.1.9/ foo